# Go: basic for loop and strconv

Tags: go

I'm a freshman for go language, and some basic things i want to ask how can we make sense for this function.
we need to use "strconv" to fix this issue.

```
  package main

import (
    "fat"
    "strconv"

)
type Student struct {
    Name string
}
func (stu *Student) Leave() {
    fmt.Println(stu.Name + " Leaving")

}

func (stu *Student) Present() {
     fmt.Println("I am " + stu.Name)

}

func main() {
  fmt.Println("Start of session")
  for i := 0; i < 6; i++ {
    s := Student{Name: fmt.Sprintf("Student%d", i)}
    s.Present()
    fmt.Println("Room Empty")
    defer s.Leave()
}
  fmt.Println("End of session")
}
```

The output should be like this

```
Start of session 
I am Student0
I am Student1
I am Student2
I am Student3
I am Student4
I am Student5 
End of session 
Student5 Leaving 
Student4 Leaving 
Student3 Leaving 
Student2 Leaving 
Student1 Leaving 
Student0 Leaving 
Room Empty
```

We need to write only one main function() and a simple for loop to get the result.

Comment: we need to write only one main function() and a simple for loop to get the result

Comment: I totally haven't any idea about that, i'm thinking to use defer and put into the for loop, but it doesn't working properly.

Comment: Do we really need "strconv" in this program. I'm thinking we don't really need this import.

Comment: @MR.S: You need `strconv` for numbers greater than one decimal digit.

Comment: Can you help me to fix this issue since i already update the new code for this program..

Comment: Stop editing your old questions into completely different questions. If you have a new question, post a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
fmt.Println("Start of session")
defer fmt.Println("Room Empty")
for i := 0; i < 6; i++ {
    s := Student{Name: "Student" + strconv.Itoa(i)}
    s.Present()
    defer s.Leave()
}
fmt.Println("End of session")
```

[playground example](http://play.golang.org/p/_wGvap-g4o)

The deferred functions are executed on return from the function in reverse order.

Comment: Hmm. We should use leave() function and "strconv", Can we do this way?

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense.

Comment: One more question, Do we really need "strconv" in this program? If we need how can we use "strconv"?

Comment: But we should use it....

Comment: 'package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"

)
type Student struct {
    Name string
}
func (stu *Student) Leave() {
    fmt.Println(stu.Name + " Leaving")

}

func (stu *Student) Present() {
     fmt.Println("I am " + stu.Name)

}
func main(){
fmt.Println("Start of session")
defer fmt.Println("Room Empty")
for i := 0; i < 6; i++ {
    s := Student{Name: "Student" + strconv.Itoa(i)}
    s.Present()
    defer s.Leave()
}
fmt.Println("End of session")
}'